# CSS Grid - Image Problems

Tags: html, css

I can not seem to place two images in different parts of a grid (Ignore the code about overlay)

I've tried referencing the images by their class and by their id's but they still are in the same grid space

When I reference the images by their id, it works because I can change the background

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homeCSS.css">
</head>

<title>
    Home Page
</title>
<header class="header">
    <h1>Welcome [User Name]</h1>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image" id="imageOrder">
            <img src="images/logo.png" class="imageLinks" id="orderForm">
            <div class="overlay" id="overlayOrder">
                <div class="overlayText" id="orderText">
                    Order Overlay
                </div>               
            </div>            
        </div>
        
        <div class="image" id="imageInvoice">
            <img src="images/logo.png" class="imageLinks" id="invoiceForm">
            <div class="overlay" id="overlayInvoice">
                <div class="overlayText" id="invoiceText">
                    Inovice Overlay
                </div>               
            </div>            
        </div>

    </div>

</body>


</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    /*max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0, auto;
  */
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap:5px;
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "imageOrder imageInvoice";
    background:#eee;
  }

  header{
      grid-area: header;
      place-self: center;
  }

  #orderForm{
      grid-area: imageOrder;
      background-color: springgreen;
  }

  #invoiceForm{
      grid-area: imageInvoice;
      background-color: chartreuse;
  }
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
  }
  

.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  /*
  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #008CBA;
  }
  */
  #imageOrder :hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /*
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    */
  }
```

An image of what it is doing (What happens when I open on Chrome)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid items need to be direct children of the grid container (in your case `body`). You, however, have a `container` div inbetween, which is assigned one single grid cell, and the contents of that div of course end up in that same cell.

Similarly, your `header` should be *inside* the grid container, ie. the body.

Answer (score -1):

You can write like this (using col-sm in bootstrap)

```css
body {
    /*max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0, auto;
  */
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap:5px;
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "imageOrder imageInvoice";
    background:#eee;
  }

  header{
      grid-area: header;
      place-self: center;
  }

  #orderForm{
      grid-area: imageOrder;
      background-color: springgreen;
  }

  #invoiceForm{
      grid-area: imageInvoice;
      background-color: chartreuse;
  }
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
  }
  

.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  /*
  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #008CBA;
  }
  */
  #imageOrder :hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /*
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    */
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homeCSS.css">
</head>

<title>
    Home Page
</title>
<header class="header">
    <h1>Welcome [User Name]</h1>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="image" id="imageOrder">
                <img src="images/logo.png" class="imageLinks" id="orderForm">
                <div class="overlay" id="overlayOrder">
                    <div class="overlayText" id="orderText">
                        Order Overlay
                    </div>               
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="image" id="imageInvoice">
                <img src="images/logo.png" class="imageLinks" id="invoiceForm">
                <div class="overlay" id="overlayInvoice">
                    <div class="overlayText" id="invoiceText">
                        Inovice Overlay
                    </div>               
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

</body>


</html>
```